# How to merge more than one XSD file to one XSD file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am not master in XML and XSD.

Just want to know how I can merge more than one XSD file to one XSD file?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: import schema's into eachother (check xsd:import/xsd:include/xsd:redefine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [import](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp) (different namespace) and [include](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_include.asp) (same namespace) multiple times. [redefine](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_redefine.asp) can also be used multiple times. It depends on what you mean by "merge."

See also http://www.herongyang.com/XML-Schema/Multiple-XSD-Schema-Document-Include-Redefine-Import.html or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee254473%28v=bts.10%29.aspx.

Edit: redefine can be used multiple times (similar to include).

Examples (validated in Eclipse) follow. I used different namespace (as the "merging" target namespace) and element names where necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/m"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/m" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- import: different (i.e. not target) namespace -->
    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/a" schemaLocation="so20046640a.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/b" schemaLocation="so20046640b.xsd"/>

    <!-- include: same namespace -->
    <include schemaLocation="so20046640c.xsd"/>
    <include schemaLocation="so20046640d.xsd"/>

    <!-- redefine: same namespace -->
    <redefine schemaLocation="so20046640e.xsd"/>
    <redefine schemaLocation="so20046640f.xsd"/>
</schema>
```

...a.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/a"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/a" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="a" type="int"/>
</schema>
```

...b.xsd: Same as ...a.xsd but target namespace .../b

...c.xsd: Same as ...a.xsd but target namespace .../m

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/m"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/m" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="a" type="int"/>
</schema>
```

...d.xsd: Same as ...c.xsd but element name b.

...e.xsd: Same as ...c.xsd but element name e.

...f.xsd: Same as ...c.xsd but element name f.

Comment: Can you please give some small examples by import, include and redefine.

Comment: How does one do it without import, include, or redefine?